# Is there a good alternative for embedding a PDF with HTML next to using a local file path, online file path or data source as base64-string?

Tags: html, pdf

I am building a web app and I would like to show PDF files to my users. My files are mainly stored as byte arrays in the database as they are generated in the backend. I am using the `embed` element and have found three ways to display a PDF:

1. Local file path in `src` attribute: Works, but I need to generate a file from the database byte array, which is not desirable as I have to manage routines to delete them once they are not needed anymore.
2. Online file path in `src` attribute: Not possible since my files may not be hosted anywhere but on the server. Also has the same issues as the previous method anyway.
3. Data as base64 string in `src` attribute: Current method, but I ran into a problem for larger files (>2MB). Edge and Chrome will not display a PDF when I covert a PDF of this size to a base64 string (no error but the docs reveal that there is a limit for the data in the `src` attribute). It works on Firefox but I cannot have my users be restricted to Firefox.

Is there any other way to transmit valid PDF data from a byte array out of the database without generating a file locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made the common mistake of thinking of URLs and file paths as the same thing; but a URL is just a string that's sent to the server, and some content is sent back. Just as you wouldn't save an HTML file to disk for every dynamic page on the site, you don't have to write to the file system to display a dynamic PDF.

So the solution to this is to have a script on your server that takes the identifier of a PDF in your system, maybe does some access checking, and outputs it to the browser.

For example, if you were using PHP, you might write the HTML with `<embed src="/loadpdf.php?id=42">` and then in `loadpdf.php` would write something like this:

```php
$pdfContent = load_pdf_from_database((int)$_GET['id']);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $pdfContent;
```

Loading `/loadpdf.php?id=42` directly in the browser would then render the PDF just the same as if it was a "real" file, and embedding it should work the same way too.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Your first paragraph gave me the edge to solve this problem. Since I wanted to re-structure my code as little as possible I simply converted my base64 string to a URL and now it works again. To clarify: I am using ASP .NET Core Razor Pages and receive the base64 string from an AJAX call. I convert this response to a blob and then URL and pass it to the embed src. Works perfectly fine even with very large documents!